# Error 500 - Premature end of script headers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

please the laravel project runs perfectly fine on locally and live server but if I reload a page, it stoped running with error code 500. I set permission but to no avail.

Error:

```
[Tue May 02 12:39:01.435531 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905975826176] [client 223.123.126.36:0] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Tue May 02 12:39:01.435535 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905975826176] (22)Invalid argument: [client 223.123.126.36:0] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
[Tue May 02 12:40:22.925119 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905833150208] [client 102.176.75.190:0] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Tue May 02 12:40:22.925186 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905833150208] [client 102.176.75.190:0] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Tue May 02 12:40:22.925190 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905833150208] (22)Invalid argument: [client 102.176.75.190:0] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
[Tue May 02 12:43:28.571488 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 9585:tid 139905715652352] [client 223.123.126.36:0] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://unified.cloudways.com/
```

Have been workaround to find a solution to this error but to no avail. What do i miss? Misconfiguration? How?